# Rearrange array into a form suitable for NN training

Tags: matlab, matrix, neural-network, dimensions, training-data

I am working on a large dataset that I need to convert to a specific format for further processing. I am looking for advice in this regard.

Sample input:

```
A = [0.99  -0.99
     1     -1
     0.55  -0.55]
```

Sample output:

```
val(:,:,1,1)=0.99
val(:,:,2,1)=-0.99
val(:,:,1,2)=1
val(:,:,2,2)=-1
val(:,:,1,3)=0.55
val(:,:,2,3)=-0.55
```

While working on this, I found a code inside the CNN toolbox of MATLAB R2018b

```
function dummifiedOut = dummify(categoricalIn)
    % iDummify   Convert a categorical input into a dummified output.
    %
    % dummifiedOut(1,1,i,j)=1 if observation j is in class i, and zero
    % otherwise. Therefore, dummifiedOut will be of size [1, 1, K, N],
    % where K is the number of categories and N is the number of
    % observation in categoricalIn.

    %   Copyright 2015-2016 The MathWorks, Inc.

    numObservations = numel(categoricalIn);
    numCategories = numel(categories(categoricalIn));
    dummifiedSize = [1, 1, numCategories, numObservations];
    dummifiedOut = zeros(dummifiedSize);
    categoricalIn = iMakeHorizontal( categoricalIn );
    idx = sub2ind(dummifiedSize(3:4), int32(categoricalIn), 1:numObservations);
    dummifiedOut(idx) = 1;
end
function vec = iMakeHorizontal( vec )
    vec = reshape( vec, 1, numel( vec ) );
end
```

Can we modify this block of code in such a way to produce the sample output?

Comment: How about `val = shiftdim(A.', -2)`

Comment: @rinkert thanks. it perfectly solves my one. can u please post your reply so that I can accept this one. I am just asking, is there any way I can manipulate the dummify() for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either do what [rinkert suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55889386/data-drepresentation-in-a-specific-format-in-matlab#comment98435938_55889386), or just use [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) directly:

```matlab
>> val = permute(A, [4,3,2,1])
val(:,:,1,1) =
    0.9900
val(:,:,2,1) =
   -0.9900
val(:,:,1,2) =
     1
val(:,:,2,2) =
    -1
val(:,:,1,3) =
    0.5500
val(:,:,2,3) =
   -0.5500
```

Note that the function which you posted requires **`categorical`** data, whereas you have a simple `double` array. If you insist on "adapting" the existing `dummify`, you could do:

```
function dummifiedOut = dummify(categoricalIn)
    dummifiedOut = zeros([1,1,size(categoricalIn)]);
    dummifiedOut(:) = categoricalIn;
end
```

(...although, IMHO, this makes little sense.)

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion. Though I understand how this code block works yet, I need to understand if I am looking for such a following output, what changes the code block may demand? Could you please highlight this issue?
Sample output:
val(:,:,1,1)=0.99
val(:,:,2,1)=-0.99
val(:,:,3,1)=0
val(:,:,4,1)=0
val(:,:,1,2)=1
val(:,:,2,2)=-1
val(:,:,3,2)=0
val(:,:,4,2)=0
val(:,:,1,3)=0.55
val(:,:,2,3)=-0.55
val(:,:,3,3)=0
val(:,:,4,3)=0

Comment: The important thing to understand is that you take a 2d array and add some singleton (i.e. of size 1) dimensions to the beginning - in this case, the 1st and 2nd, without changing the data. If you understand this, you should realize that ending up with those extra zeros, you can just modify the original input. To get the output you showed, you would need to add a couple of zero columns to the right side of matrix `A` before calling `permute` or `dummify`. See also `padarray`.